# How to create a sticky header in React using useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to create a sticky header in React using the useEffect hook. I think the issue is with my IF statement logic, but it's just going straight over my head.

My navbar seems to stick fine once scrolled past, but when scrolling back up to the top it doesn't "unstick". Console logging "stuck" shows that it doesn't seem to change from false...

```js
    const [ stuck, setStuck ] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
            console.log(stuck);
            if (stuck === false) {
                if (window.pageYOffset > 131) {
                    setStuck(true);
                    console.log('stuck');
                }
            } else {
                if (window.pageYOffset < 131) {
                    setStuck(false);
                    console.log('unStuck');
                }
            }
        });
    }, []);
```

returning a navbar that roughly looks like this...

```js
            <div
                className={classes.Links}
                style={
                    stuck ? (
                        { position: 'fixed', top: '0', width: '100%', left: '0' }
                    ) : (
                        { left: toggle ? '0' : '-100%' }
                    )
                }>
                <ul></ul>
              </div>
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: If you want to create sticky header, then why you are using react hooks for it.  It can be simply done with HTML, CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is a tricky one. When you use the useEffect hook, it gets a closure on the current instance of the variables in the function, so on your first pass, the `stuck` variable is set to the default value of `false`, which the arrow function in the useEffect gets a closure of.

When `setStuck` is called, it will alter the components state and cause a rerender. This new render will run through all of the logic in your function again. It will call `useState`, and that will return your stored value for `stuck`, which is now true, but it stores this in a new reference. In your example, `useEffect` has no dependencies, so it will not be executed on subsequent renders. The function that you have added to the event listener still has a closure on the version of the function from last time it ran, and thus, as far as the event listener is concerned, stuck still equals `false`. Its closure is from the previous version of the function.

In most simple cases, you would just need to add `stuck` in as a dependency on your call to `useEffect`. That would cause it to be rerun when `stuck` changes, and it would re add the callback with a new closure to the correct value. The problem here is that you will have to remove the callback every time you want to change the state.

So I suggest when you call `setStuck`, you also use that time to remove the callback handler. Then a rerender will happen and add it back in, but now with a closure on the correct values